# Infix to reverse polish notation (RPN)

Tags: notation

I have an example: m = n = p = (-1) ^ (m + n + p) * (m + n + p);
I don't know what to do with multiple "=". Should I treat them as a sign with the lowest priority or just put them in end of the answer?
That's what I get when I treat them as sign with the lowest prioryty:
M,N,=,P,=,1,NEG,M,N,+,P,+,^,M,N,+,P,+,*,=
Could you check my answer?

Comment: We typically don't check answers over here. This is your teaching assistant's job. We can help clear any conceptual doubts.

Comment: To answer your more conceptual question, usually "=" associates to the right, that is, $a=b=c$ is the same as $a=(b=c)$, and everything else should follow from that. But ultimately, only *you* can say what grammar of expressions you are using.